# Is there a C/C++ binding of Apache Jena?

Tags: java, c++, swig, sparql, jena

I'm looking for a SPARQL parser and i find Apache Jena/arq and Redland librdf.
But Jena has been written in Java,so is there a way that I use Jena's APIs in C/C++, (maybe with SWIG,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what functionality you need, it may be plausible to interact with an [Apache Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) server via the [SPARQL 1.1 Protocol](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/). Fuseki *is* Jena, just wrapped in a Jetty service in order to implement the protocol.

If this is far heavier than what you are looking for, and you desire interacting with Jena from C/C++, then [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (or better yet, some automated wrapper like SWIG) *may* be your best bet.